# NonLinearModelFit of sigmoidal looking data

Tags: curve-fitting

I have a sigmoidal looking set of data for protein unfolding. I want to find enthalpy (H), mid temperature(Tm), and 4 other variables (ad,bd,an,bn) with a non-linear model.
My data are T for temperature and y for the circular dichroism signal (for percentage folded).

Here is the equation:

```
k = exp((H/(R*T))*(T/Tm - 1));
y = ((ad + bd*T)/(1 + k) + (an + bn*T)*k/(1 + k));
```

I tried:

```
fit=lsqcurvefit(T,y,'Y')
```

It didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

that is because the cost function does not have the global minimum. Eventually the algorithm finds just a local minimum. Try to modify and fit this one x/sqrt(1+x^2)